# Switched to new router and now experiencing lag?

Tags: ps3, networking

I switched from a Dynex-802.11b/g to a Netgear-802.11b/g/n just yesterday. My router is downstairs because my phone-line upstairs doesn't work very well, but my PS3 is still upstairs (SOCOM: Confrontation is the game with which I am experiencing issues).

I have done everything I can to make sure the connection is solid and have checked the status and it has been as high as 80% and usually lingers at about 60%. I thought about upgrading my bandwidth from 1.5mbs to 7mbs, but I am guessing something is wrong if it worked fine before. The game seems more laggy and my voice chat is choppy. Others seem to receive my voice data fine because I can hear my own feedback clearly from other players (if you are in close proximity to another player and speak, sometimes their volume is loud enough sometimes you can hear yourself).

I wonder if porting forward or setting up DMZ will fix this problem, but I am not sure and don't know quite how to do it. Has anyone else ever experienced this when switching routers? What did you do to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest adding a link to your identical superuser question.

Comment: Considering that it was the router that was changed, I think you'll end up getting better help from [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: crossposted question is [here](http://superuser.com/q/245434/41594).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, that could very well be the problem. I would suggest that you assign a fixed IP to your PS3 and make that IP the default DMZ host.

Here is how you do that.

1. Open a Web browser, and type the router's IP address. Put password etc.
2. From the Main Menu of the browser interface, under Advanced, click Port Forwarding to view the port forwarding menu. OR Advanced > Security ( depending on your router model )
3. Pick an IP address and set it as the DMZ host.
4. Now follow [these](http://portforward.com/networking/staticip-ps3-playstation-3.htm) instructions ( with pics :D ) and set the same IP here.
5. In your PS3 go to Settings > Network Settings > Internet Connection Test.
   Look for NAT Type, if it is Type 2 (open) you are all set.